# If $a_{n}$ diverges to $+\infty$ and $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$ are asymptotically equal, then $a_{n}\ln(a_{n})$,$b_{n}\ln(b_{n})$ are asymptotically equal.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help with this.
I thought it was easy, but I cant prove it.

$a_{n}$, $b_{n}$ are asymptotically equal iff $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}}=1$.

Let $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$ sequences of real numbers, such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{a_{n}}=+\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}}=1$. Prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{\frac{a_{n}\ln(a_{n})}{b_{n}\ln(b_{n})}}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(a_n)/\ln(b_n) = 1$. Define $c_n$ by $a_n=b_nc_n$; this is defined for all sufficiently large $n$ since $b_n\to\infty$. We have $c_n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. Now we get $\ln(a_n)/ln(b_n)=(\ln(b_n)+\ln(c_n))/\ln(b_n)=1+\ln(c_n)/\ln(b_n)$, which tends to $1$ since $\ln(c_n)\to 0$ and $\ln(b_n)\to\infty$.

Comment: I think you took $b_{n}$ as $a_{n}$.But there is no problem with the prove. Thanks!